# Killing a long running Loop C# IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

I have a long running loop that kicks off in my web app on IIS running my C# code.  I'm in development mode, so I'm attaching to the W3P3 process often, testing my loop, troubleshooting, etc.. and when I kill my interactive session in Visual Studio the loop keeps running.  This is expected.  What is not expected, is that after I kill the current running W3P3 process, the loop continues to perform.  I have tested this many times and I just can't quite figure out how to kill the loop (kill the process, which process?).
I have no intent of coding, "is client still connected", because it is the correct behavior to continue to run, whether or not the client is connected or not, however in development mode I need to be able to kill it.
Which process is persisting and running the loop?

Comment: "What is not expected, is that after I kill the current running W3P3 process, the loop continues to perform." So if you are not able to share more information on that (like a complete video clip on how to verify that), I can only assume you killed the wrong process. `appcmd list wp` should tell you more about which process is the correct one.

Comment: @LexLi just to confirm, it could only be the W3P3 process that is persisting the loop?  In killing it, you'd assume the loop would die with it?

Comment: OK.  I started my long running web app loop, then issued the cmd taskkill /IM w3wp.exe /F, and got back a SUCCESS, and noticed my app was still running so I issued the same command and got back a SUCCESS again and then again and same thing a SUCCESS.  After the 3rd kill, my long running loop finally is killed.  So 3 instances of the W3WP process is running.

Comment: So you mean that there are 3 W3Wp processes starting and running when you run application for one time? But how could it create 3 processes?